# ASP redirect all incoming requests

Tags: asp.net

Hi pardon my ignorance i'm coming from an apache background.

On IIS/ASP.NET (.NET 4.0) is it possible to redirect all incoming requests to a page for for maintenance and such.  I tried just using a 404 redirect but it doesn't seem to cut it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an [App_Offline.html](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx) file when you want to bring an ASP.NET site into maintenance mode:

> The way app_offline.htm works is that you place this file in the root
>   of the application.  When ASP.NET sees it, it will shut-down the
>   app-domain for the application (and not restart it for requests) and
>   instead send back the contents of the app_offline.htm file in response
>   to all new dynamic requests for the application.  When you are done
>   updating the site, just delete the file and it will come back online.